# What is a 'Partition' in Apache Helix

Tags: apache, distributed-computing, high-availability, helix

I am learning Apache Helix. I came across the keyword 'Partitions'.

According to the definition mentioned here http://helix.apache.org/Concepts.html, Each subtask (of a main task) is referred to as a partition in Helix.
When I gone through the recipe - Distributed Lock Manager, partitions are nothing but instances of a resource. (Increase the numOfPartitions, number of locks is increased).

```
final int numPartitions = 12;
admin.addResource(clusterName, lockGroupName, numPartitions, "OnlineOffline",
          RebalanceMode.FULL_AUTO.toString());
```

Can someone explain with simple example, what exactly the partition in Apache Helix is ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right that a partition is essentially an instance of a resource. As is the case in other distributed systems, partitions are used to achieve parallelism. A resource with only one instance can only run on one machine. Partitions simply provide the construct necessary to split a single resource among many machines by, well, partitioning the resource.

This is a pattern that is found in a large portion of distributed systems. The difference, though, is while e.g. distributed databases explicitly define partitions essentially as a subset of some larger data set that can fit on a single node, Helix is more generic in that partitions don't have a definite meaning or use case, but many potential meanings and potential use cases.

One of these use cases in a system with which I'm very familiar is Apache Kafka's topic partitions. In Kafka, each topic - essentially a distributed log - is broken into a number of partitions. While the topic data can be spread across many nodes in the cluster, each partition is constrained to a single log on a single node. Kafka provides scalability by adding new partitions to new nodes. When messages are produced to a Kafka topic, internally they're hashed to some specific partition on some specific node. When messages are consumed from a topic, the consumer switches between partitions - and thus nodes - as it consumes from the topic.

This pattern generally applies to many scalability problems and is found in almost any HA distributed database (e.g. DynamoDB, Hazelcast), map/reduce (e.g. Hadoop, Spark), and other data or task driven systems.

The [LinkedIn blog post about Helix](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/ad-hoc-task-management-apache-helix) actually gives a bunch of useful examples of the relationships between resources and partitions as well.

Comment: Thanks @kuujo,  your answer was very helpful. I forgot to mark it as accepted, so i just did it now.